# ggplot2: extract data for points along lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to extract xy coordinates for points along a curved line in a ggplot.  `ggplot_build()` shows some of the data, but it still only contains the start and end coordinates of the curve.  Is there any way to get at the intermediate points?

Edit:
Example code using `geom_curve()`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend=yend)) + geom_curve(curvature = .4)
```

Comment: Can you provide us with the code you employed to plot the curve? I'd be surprised if what you are looking for could not be infered or extracted from either the source dataframe or the instructions (i.e. equation) you gave ggplot to plot the curve.

Comment: I've added the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my best attempt, given the info you've supplied. If you could provide a reproducible example, perhaps a better solution could be supplied.

```
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) +
  geom_smooth()
x_coords <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]$x
y_coords <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]$y

p
```

[image: ggplot]

```
plot(x_coords, y_coords, type = "l")
```

[image: base]

Comment: Thanks, but this already has points. Rather, I'm trying to get points along a curve that isn't generated with intermediate points. Sorry for the lack of example (it's there now)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. The best I could do was to use `geom_smooth()` with arguments `method` and `formula` that best fit my line. `geom_smooth()` necessarily generates many more of these intermediate points you are looking for. In turn, `ggplot_build()` enables you to extract the newly generated intermediate points.

However, this approach does not allow you to dictate which intermediate points to generate and therefore extract. I addressed this by explicitly creating a model object from the same smoothing `method` and `formula` implied in `geom_smooth()`. In my case, this was `mysmoothmodel <- stats::loess(hwy ~ cty, data = mpg)`. This object in conjunction with `predict(mysmoothmodel, newdata = data.frame(cty = x_coords_of_intermediate)` will estimate the y coordinate you are looking for.

Comment: Wihan, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137510/how-do-i-estimate-the-coordinates-of-points-along-a-graphed-line-in-r - this might help you